# disgenet2r enrichment analysis timeout error, curl::curl_fetch_memory error

Tags: timeout, connection-timeout

I am trying to use the [disgenet2r Rpackage](https://www.disgenet.org/home/) to run an enrichment analysis for a list of mouse genes. The package connects to the disgenet database through an api key

```
disgenet_api_key <- get_disgenet_api_key(
                  email = email, 
                  password = password )
Sys.setenv(DISGENET_API_KEY= disgenet_api_key)
```

Installation and API key activation work fine, however when I try to run the analysis with `disease_enrichment` the code always gives me the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [www.disgenet.org] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

I even tried running it with the vignette example and I get the same error, so I am thinking is not an issue with my data but more with my computer and internet connection:

```
list_of_genes <- disease2gene(disease = "C0004352", database = "GENOMICS_ENGLAND")

list_of_genes <- list_of_genes@qresult$gene_symbol

res_enrich <- disease_enrichment( entities = list_of_genes, vocabulary = "HGNC",
                             database = "CURATED" )
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [www.disgenet.org] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

(the actual count of the total milliseconds changes everytime, but I don't think is relevant)

I have no idea how to tackle this issue. I'm currently connect to a eduroam wifi through Google DNS, I do not know if this could be relevant.
I would appreciate any help.